# How to retrieve sound from a turntable via USB

Tags: audio-recording

I have a turntable which has a USB made for digitalizing Vinyl records via USB (usb A to usb B not audio to usb). It came with a disk that had "EZ Vinyl/Tape Archiver" which requires itunes to run. What program can receive audio data and record it?

Comment: If the turntable presents itself as a basic sound card with an audio input then any program capable of recording sound will work.

Comment: What's the output of `lsusb`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use audacity for this purpose. To install, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

According to [this post](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2008/08/30/how-to-digitize-records-with-ubuntu-a-usb-turntable-and-audacity/), just select Edit-Preferences, and in "Recording" select "ALSA: USB Audio CODEC: USB Audio (hw:1,0)" input. Then, press record and drop the needle.

Realtime playback is kind of tricky and I can't remember exactly how to get that working. Supposedly, Ubuntu devs decided to do away with that by default because of feedback from microphone input which is inherit with any professional recording setup and was a real dumb move for them to change but I digress. Anyway, it *is* possible; you just have to figure it out.

Comment: i wana do that on my computer but theeres no internet yet. i went to ublic wifi with my laptop and downloaded the .deb but it gave an entire list of dependencies. Whre can i get a package that comes with all the required programs? 14.04

Comment: @NickBailuc After installing the deb using the `dpkg -i` command, I think you can use this command: `sudo apt-get -f install` of course it won't install anything but it should give you a list of packages to install before throwing a bunch of errors. You can download those debs and install them one by one using `dpkg -i`. Or you could download the Ubuntustudio iso from here https://ubuntustudio.org/download/. It comes with audacity pre-installed so you can use it as a live disk to do the recording or install it to your computer.

Comment: @NickBailuc and if you do some digging you might be able to figure out how to extract and install the needed packages from the mounted iso. Either way Ubuntustudio has everything you need if you have the time to download the iso. Plus, the Ubuntustudio kernel is lowlatency so it's better for recording anyway.